# Upgrading to testng 7.5.1 breaks Spring Tests

Tags: java, spring, testng

I upgraded testng from 6.14.3 to 7.5.1 in my application which is running Spring 6.1.5.

Post the testng upgrade, I start getting the error

> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] The following methods have cyclic dependencies:
> [ERROR] AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextBeforeTestClass()[pri:0, instance:null]
> [ERROR] AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance()[pri:0, instance:null]
> [ERROR] AbstractComponentTest.parentSetupClass()[pri:0, instance:null]

Any idea how I can fix these cyclic dependencies?

Comment: `7.5.1` is the last version that works with JDK8. `7.9.0` (needs JDK11 btw) is the latest released version. Any issues with TestNG will see a fix ONLY on top of `7.9.0`. So you might want to first upgrade to `7.9.0` and try again. If the problem persists, I will suggest that you file a bug in the TestNG github project with a sample that can be used to reproduce the issue.